# store theme colour with jQuery

Tags: jquery, local-storage, page-refresh

HTML part

```
<div class="theme_toggle">
    <div class="theme_toggle_light">
         <img src="assets/images/light.png" alt="" class="theme_toggle_img">
    </div>
    <div class="theme_toggle_dark">
          <img src="assets/images/dark.png" alt="" class="theme_toggle_img">
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery part

```
$('.theme_toggle_dark').click(function () {
     $('body').attr('class', 'dark');
 })
 $('.theme_toggle_light').click(function () {
     $('body').removeClass('dark');
 })
```

I want that when I refresh the page if the dark class is added to the body it should be stored and if I press to remove the dark class then it should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local storage.

```
$('.theme_toggle_dark').click(function() {
  $('body').addClass('dark');
  localStorage.setItem('darkClass', 'true');
});

$('.theme_toggle_light').click(function() {
  $('body').removeClass('dark');
  localStorage.removeItem('darkClass');
});

// Check if the 'darkClass' item exists in local storage on page load
if (localStorage.getItem('darkClass') === 'true') {
  $('body').addClass('dark');
}
```

This will set the `darkClass` item in local storage to `true` when the `dark` class is added to the body, and remove the item from local storage when the `dark` class is removed.

On page load, the code will check for the presence of the `darkClass` item in local storage, and reapply the `dark` class to the body if it exists.